# Custom Admin controller not working

Tags: admin, error, adminhtml, controllers, admin-controller

I am developing a module & created admin controller but working on url

```
mymagentosite.com/index.php/admin/transaction/index
```

show error:There has been an error processing your request

error in the file is

```
a:5:{i:0;s:51:"Controller file was loaded but class does not exist";i:1;s:1106:".../magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(326): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Controller file...')
```

code is here
Namespace/Modulename/etc/config.xml

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <modulename before="Mage_Adminhtml">Namesapce_Modulename_Adminhtml</modulename>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

Namespace/Modulename/controller/Adminhtml/TransationController.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Adminhtml_TransationController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "string";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear about it:

```
Controller file was loaded but class does not exist
```

So the controller file has been loaded but the class name is wrong. Class name and file name in your question seem to match, but I noticed that `TransationController` probably should read `TransactionController` ("C" is missing).

Double check that file name and class name match

Answer (score 1):

fschmengler's answer is correct. There is another type in `config.xml` with a and p swapped in Namespace: `Namesapce_Modulename_Adminhtml`

Should be `Namespace_Modulename_Adminhtml`.